# Is my normal interpolation perspectively correct

Tags: c++, 3d, rendering, renderer

I am trying to implement a software renderer

It looks like this, it seems my interpolated normal is not perspectively correct

[image]

I use scanline conversion and calculate normal with following steps:

Assume we are now drawing line AB (A B have same y value in screen space)

1. Calculating normal of B by interpolating normals of Top vertex and bottom vertex. (Alpha and Beta value is retrieve from top and bottom in screen space)
2. to calculate A is similar
3. draw line AB. Calculating the normals of fragments by interpolating normals of A and B
4. calc light contribution

[image]

If I am doing wrong, how to do correct interpolation?

Comment: texcoord is calculate the same way as normal, it "looks" nicer than normal. but it might be wrong too